# Query result size in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a good way to know the query response size in Redshift?

Other providers create a temporary table (or you can do it) and then, check the table size. In Redshift, a temporary table does not have an entry in *svv_table_info* view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a temp table does work for your case and the size of all tables can be found by looking at stv_blocklist.  Since every table is composed of blocks and all blocks are 1MB in size this gives a "from the horses mouth" size for the table.  Just remember that this gives the blocks needed to store the table and in some cases this can be misleading - DISTSTYLE ALL tables will have N copies of the data.  In general this is a good way to find the size of any table.  You can also query the number of rows in the temp table for a different size assessment.

The downside of the temp table approach is the time it takes to setup and organize the data into a table.  You still need to select this data for output assuming that is the intent once the size has been assessed.  A more common, but more advanced approach for dealing with potentially oversized output is to set up a cursor to hold the output.

A cursor is an output buffer on the Redshift leader node that holds the results of a query before transmitting to the requesting client.  Then the cursor contents can be read in chunks of row (10,000 typically) and when more data is needed, more rows are read.  Many BI tools will use cursors so that malformed reports don't swamp the tool with too much data.  You can also query the size (rows and bytes) of a cursor by looking at stv_active_cursors.

The downside of cursors is that they require work from the leader node, not much, but some.  Significant over-use / mis-use of cursors can slow the leader down or potentially fill up the leader node's disks (but this is unlikely since the leader has the same disk size as a compute node but not as much data to store).  Also since cursors are read in a loop, fetch then process, fetch then process, the client is typically an application and not a user.  However, I have done cursors interactively in order to see the size of the output before I pull it out over the network - run query to cursor, read the size of the cursor, and then if the size is ok read the entire cursor in one chunk.

Bottom line - cursors could be the solution you are looking for (I can't really tell without the use case being described).

Comment: WoW, thank you Bill, amazing response. I am going to check both

Comment: About temp tables, they do not appear in *STV_BLOCKLIST* or *SVV_DISKUSAGE* view. Perhaps it is because these views are visible only to superuser, but it is working for non-temporary tables. This is the query I am doing `SELECT count(stv_blocklist.*) as size
FROM stv_blocklist, stv_tbl_perm
WHERE stv_blocklist.tbl = stv_tbl_perm.id
AND stv_blocklist.slice = stv_tbl_perm.slice
AND stv_tbl_perm.name = 'MY_TEMP_TABLE_NAME'`

Comment: The cursor one is working but sizes are far apart from the ones from *svv_table_info* view. For tables under 50MB, cursor size is half of the table info view. For tables over 300MB, cursor is bigger. Maybe I haven't tested tables large enough, but so far the cursor always returns the total size with all rows, even when you ask just for a few rows which is nice for us.

Comment: For the record, some numbers checking *svv_table_info* view (table) and *STV_ACTIVE_CURSORS* view (cursor) in MB:
`cursor: 5.5
table: 12
downloaded JSON file: 4.6`

`cursor: 17
table: 27
downloaded JSON file: 37`

`cursor: 1339
table: 314`

`cursor: 2196
table: 1249`

Comment: Tables in Redshift are made up of blocks which are 1MB and are compressed.  A cursor is a buffer of the soon-to-be outgoing result data.  The first row of a table will take 1MB per column if it is in a table but only the bytes needed to represent the data for the cursor.  However when the data get large Redshift columnar compression saves a ton of space. As for JSON, it is a highly space inefficient representation of data as the header information is repeated for each "row".  Your data makes sense to me.  Apples, grapes and watermelons.

Comment: I agree with comparing JSON file with table/cursor size, of course. But I don't see why the relation between cursor/table sizes is not more or less continuous. I would expect tables sizes are always smaller (compressed) than cursor (uncompressed). Even when table compression rates improve with bigger sizes, in small tables compression should make tables smaller than the cursor, isn't it?. So for sure, I am missing something. I think we can live with that if we always use the same way to get the size, so we don't mix apples and pears :) Thank you very much Bill!

Comment: This comes down to how Redshift stores data on disk.  The unit of storage is a block which is 1MB in size.  To store any data for a column requires 1MB and each column has independent storage (columnar).  Also each slice's data is also independent so each column on each slice is 1MB of storage.  There are also 3 hidden columns in every table.  So to store 1 row of a 7 column table will take 10MB on disk no matter how well it is compressed.  Redshift is optimized for big tables, not small.  A cursor for this same data is likely less than 1K in size.  This is the extreme case.